# how can i passs input in adb shell using python script?

Tags: python, command, adb

I am facing a problem, have to pass an input after I run command: adb shell libtest_ip through python:

```
 import subprocess
 command = 'adb shell libtest_ip'
 p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

after this I have to pass input like 1 or en_us etc.. but as soon as the command to sun binary(libtest_ip is a binary), is executed, it gets stuck.

Please help me if anyone have idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) .
Specially you can take a look at [script.py](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/script.py) that would help you creating the interactive script.

Basically, you should end up with something like this

```
    ...
    self.child.expect('Whatever')
    self.child.sendline('1')
    self.child.expect('Whatever 2')
    self.child.sendline('en-us')
    ...
```

## update

Your example should work, try

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pexpect
print(pexpect.run('/bin/echo hello'))
```

and running it should output

```
% ./test-pexpect.py 
b'hello\r\n'
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sshukl16/Desktop/Personal/myPrograms/pespect_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(pexpect.run('echo hello'))
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'run'

Getting above error when using pexpect.run